# Youtube embed code custom width and height

Tags: html, flash, youtube, youtube-api

Hello I am trying to embed a custom youtube player [here](http://crimestoppers.thestagingurl.com/multi-media/)

The problem is im unable to set a custom height and width for it. It seems to leave some ugly whitespace and doesnt fully stretch.

```
<object width="540" height="350">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/cp/vjVQa1PpcFOEm1zAacTga1hxrmYl7Q0lOFesqks2LI="></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/cp/vjVQa1PpcFOEm1zAacTga1hxrmYl7Q0-lOFesqks2LI=" allownetworking="internal" width="540" height="350"></embed></object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wmode=transparent, the whitespace of the flash object will turn transparent.
Works fine in firefox.

```
  <object width="540" height="350"><param value="http://www.youtube.com/cp/vjVQa1PpcFOEm1zAacTga1hxrmYl7Q0lOFesqks2LI=" name="movie">
<param value="transparent" name="wmode">
    <embed width="540" height="350" wmode="transparent" allownetworking="internal" src="http://www.youtube.com/cp/vjVQa1PpcFOEm1zAacTga1hxrmYl7Q0-lOFesqks2LI="></object>
```

Comment: using your answer but I want to increase its width